# Como mudar o tipo de texto numa lista com JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Como é que eu posso fazer um efeito no texto dentro das listas com JQuery?

Por exemplo, quando o rato passa por cima do texto nas listas, a cor fica mais clara e o texto fica sublinhado.

```css
p {
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 80%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

#pagina {
  margin: 20px;
}

#logo {
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: georgia;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#nav {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 62px;
}

#nav ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}

#conteudo {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#rodape {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#rodape p {
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: grey;
}

.caixa {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}

.caixa-redonda {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="logo">
    <h1>>O nosso Web Site</h1>
  </div>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="caixa" href="index.html">Início</a></li>
      <li><a class="caixa" href="#sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a class="caixa" href="contactar.html">Contactar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section id="pagina">
  <div id="conteudo" class="caixa">
    <h2>Início</h2>
    <p>
      Este é o meu site! Consegui codificar todo o HTML e CSS de modo a este funcionar. Atenção Mundo da Web que acabei de chegar!!!
    </p>
    <p>
      Vou usar as minhas aptidões para criar todo o tipo de websites, inclusive para a disciplina de RC.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <p>
    Página Criada por: <a href="/" target="_blank">[Davide]</a>
  </p>
</footer>
```

Comment: 1 - Edite sua pergunta e coloque seu código aqui. 2 - Que efeito está se referindo?

Comment: Poderia detalhar melhor que tipo de efeito você está querendo fazer?

Comment: Vc quer fazer um efeito tipo o que?

Comment: Por exemplo, quando o rato passa por cima do texto nas listas, a cor fica mais clara e o texto fica sublinhado

Comment: O código é este: https://jsfiddle.net/50qcszhe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta vc incluir esse código no seu css

```
#nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline; /* deixa o texto sublinhado */
  background: rgba(250,180,74,0.5); /* deixa o laranja com uma opacidade*/
}
```

Se quiser uma transição suave das cores use `transition: background 500ms linear;`  na sua `#nav ul li a { ... }`

Veja como fica direto no código

```css
  p {
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 80%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

#pagina {
  margin: 20px;
}

#logo {
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: georgia;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#nav {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 62px;
}

#nav ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
transition: background 500ms linear; /* faza  transição suave dascores */
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background: rgba(250,180,74,0.5);
}

#conteudo {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#rodape {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#rodape p {
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: grey;
}

.caixa {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}

.caixa-redonda {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <div id="logo">
          <h1>>O nosso Web Site</h1>
        </div>
        <nav id="nav">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="caixa" href="index.html">Início</a></li>
            <li><a class="caixa" href="#sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
            <li><a class="caixa" href="contactar.html">Contactar</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
  
      <section id="pagina">
        <div id="conteudo" class="caixa">
          <h2>Início</h2>
          <p>
            Este é o meu site! Consegui codificar todo o HTML e CSS de modo a este funcionar. Atenção Mundo da Web que acabei de chegar!!!
          </p>
          <p>
            Vou usar as minhas aptidões para criar todo o tipo de websites, inclusive para a disciplina de RC.
          </p>
        </div>
      </section>
  
      <footer>
        <p>
          Página Criada por: <a href="/" target="_blank">[Davide]</a>
        </p>
      </footer>
```

Comment: Obrigado! Estava mesmo a precisar disto :D

Comment: @D.Rodrigues legal que deu certo ai estude bem os código! Sealguma resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta que vc escolher. Assim o site não fica com sua pergunta aberta mesmo já tendo sido resolvida.

Comment: Obrigado! Já o fiz, agora tenho que continuar o código

Comment: @D.Rodrigues segui com o trabalho, e sempre estamos aqui para ajudar caso tenha outra dúvida! ;)

Comment: Por acaso preciso de ajuda com uma coisa em php! Preciso de dizer ao utilizador a sua passe, só que com as primeiras 3 letras com asterico e as outras sem asterico!

Comment: Não sei se agora pode ajudar, mas tenho o PHP assim:

<?php 
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

if ($user != null && $pass != null)
    echo "Bem vindo ".$user .", a tua passe é esta: ".$pass;
else
    echo "Tens que tentar outra vez";
?>

Comment: @D.Rodrigues eu não entendo nada de PHP rss, mas te indico que abra uma Nova Pergunta,. coloque seu código e de uma explicação detalhada. Aqui no site tem muita gente excelente em PHP que vai te responder rapidinho!

Comment: @D.Rodrigues: `$pass =  substr($pass, 0, 3) . '***';`

Comment: Consegui fazer o que precisava, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Isso que você quer fazer, você consegue com CSS mesmo, não precisa de JS.

Basta adicionar essas linhas no seu CSS

```
#conteudo:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #999;
}
```

A mágica está na propriedade `:hover`, que aplica o estilo exatamente quando se passa o mouse em cima do elemento que está a sua frete (`elemento:hover`), você pode ver mais [AQUI](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

```css
p {
  line-height: 1em;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  margin: 0 0 .5em 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 80%;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

#pagina {
  margin: 20px;
}

#logo {
  width: 35%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-family: georgia;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#nav {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: right;
  float: right;
}

#nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 62px;
}

#nav ul li a {
  padding: 20px;
  background: orange;
  color: white;
}

#conteudo {
  margin: 30px 0;
  padding: 20px;
  clear: both;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#conteudo:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  background-color: #999;
}

#rodape {
  border-bottom: 1px #ccc solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#rodape p {
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 80%;
  color: grey;
}

.caixa {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
}

.caixa-redonda {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #999;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Os vossos nomes" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


    <title>O meu Website de RC</title>



  </head>

  <body>

    <header>
      <div id="logo">
        <h1>>O nosso Web Site</h1>
      </div>
      <nav id="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="caixa" href="index.html">Início</a></li>
          <li><a class="caixa" href="#sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a class="caixa" href="contactar.html">Contactar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section id="pagina">
      <div id="conteudo" class="caixa">
        <h2>Início</h2>
        <p>
          Este é o meu site! Consegui codificar todo o HTML e CSS de modo a este funcionar. Atenção Mundo da Web que acabei de chegar!!!
        </p>
        <p>
          Vou usar as minhas aptidões para criar todo o tipo de websites, inclusive para a disciplina de RC.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
      <p>
        Página Criada por: <a href="/" target="_blank">[Davide]</a>
      </p>
    </footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Desculpa, acabei adicionando o que você queria no Card kkk É só seguir a resposta do hugo que vai dar certo, mas se quiser no Card pode seguir a minha kkk

Comment: Não há problema, obrigado!

Comment: Muito boa a resposta Eduardo.